# WCF Impersonation doubts

Tags: wcf, impersonation, delegation

What impersonation level is required when implementing a service that needs to access out-of-process resources on behalf of the original caller?

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.tokenimpersonationlevel.aspx)

> **Impersonation**:    The server process can impersonate the client's
>   security context on its local system. The server cannot impersonate
>   the client on remote systems.
>
> **Delegation**    The server process can
>   impersonate the client's security context on remote systems.

Am I correct in assuming that **Impersonation** is sufficient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you stay on the same machine: Yes impersonation is enough. In or out of process does not matter.